# How do I parse the extended CSS braces in the markdown created by pelican-import?

Tags: css, markdown, pelican

I used pelican-import, creating a series of markdown files from a wordpress export file.

```
pelican-import --wpfile -o wpexport/ -m markdown wordpress.xml
```

A markdown file was created for each article from the wordpress backup.  The images are represented in the markdown like this:

```
[alt-text](img.jpg){.size-medium .wp-image-206 .alignnone width="300" height="300"}
```

The curly braces aren't being parsed by pelican, and don't seem to be part of the markdown standard.

Is there a markdown plugin or pelican extension that parses this output?
[markdown.extras.attr_list](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/attr_list.html) is the closest I can find, but it has slightly different syntax.

Comment: Have you tried it? While not documented, the colon is optional in the attr_list extension so that should work just fine

Comment: I tried it, but it's possible I didn't enable the plugin properly.

Comment: Brilliant.  Just needed to correctly enable the plugin.  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The braces were attr_list syntax after all.  I just needed to enable the plugin correctly.  MD_EXTENSIONS had been deprecated.

add to pelicanconf.py:

```
MARKDOWN = {
    'extensions': ['extra'],
    'output_format': 'html5',
}
```